# C# Serialize/Deserialize to/from a WebService (BizTalk Published Schema) with namespace

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, biztalk-2013

I have a C# console program with a webservice reference to a BizTalk published schema.  It's a huge beasty program and I'm trying to create a small test harness to just retrieve an XML file and post it, but making sure it conforms.

When I build an object in memory and serialize it, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Outbound210 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Transaction xmlns="http://ABC.Integrations/" />
</Outbound210>
```

The primary question is why the namespace of "http://ABC.Integrations" is on the  element and not on the root  element. 
The corollary issue is that if I try to serialize a file with that namespace on the root, I get the error:

Exception: There is an error in XML document (1,2) 
  Inner Exception:  was not expected.

The Schema root is called "Outbound210", and the first part of the references.cs (built from the WSDL is shown below).

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://ABC.Integrations/")]
public partial class Outbound210 : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Outbound210Transaction transactionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public Outbound210Transaction Transaction {
        get {
            return this.transactionField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Transaction");
        }
    }

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://ABC.Integrations/")]
public partial class Outbound210Transaction : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    etc...
```

Code to deserialize is:

```
Outbound210 outbound210 = new Outbound210();
Outbound210Transaction outbound210Trans = new Outbound210Transaction();
outbound210.Transaction = outbound210Trans; 

XmlSerializer xs1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Outbound210));
StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(@"d:\SVN\Demo\Verify.xml");
xs1.Serialize(sw1, outbound210);
sw1.Close();
```

Interestingly enough, when I put the namespace on  and not the root, it serializes, and then it submits to the webservice and processes through BizTalk okay, and there is shows the namespace on the root (in message tracking). My expectation is I should be able to serialize the exact same file that is seen in BizTalk with the namespace on the root, and not the second element.

Comment: Attempting to apply the namespace to the root means you're sending a different document than what the service expects. You shouldn't care how the service defines its namespaces--you just need to match what it says it needs. If you add a Service Reference using the BizTalk WSDL, then the class that VS generates should allow you to communicate with the web service.

Comment: Not sure I follow you; in BizTalk the root has the namespace, and the C# generated above seems to have it too. But yet when I specify it on serialization, it blows up (as described), and when I deserialize, it is missing.